# Dynamic Memory bytes needed

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, byte

What is the total amount of memory necessary (in Bytes) to create a 4 x 3 x 3 array of doubles dynamically?

I know the answer is 356 but simply do not understand where the extra bytes are coming from. A lille help please?

Comment: hey.. how in the world you got 356? :-)

Comment: @G_G I can see 1 pointer to the entire array, 4 pointers on the second dimension and 12 pointers on the third dimension which altogether gives us 17 values of some integer type (platform dependent). Assuming 32 bit integer it makes another 68 bytes. So it's 356 bytes together with 288 bytes for doubles - at least.

Comment: I don't get it, maybe you are overcomplicating things. I assume you can address any double on your array using a simple integer index (i.e. any multi-dimensional array can be reduced to a linear array plus some minor index pre-manipulation)

Comment: @G_G but you can always access variable holding a pointer at any level of multidimensional array and assign a value to it pointing to newly allocated sub-array. It's not about how you can access elements of that array. It's about memory management for this data structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as @user4815162342 says, you need at least 288 bytes for doubles but he/she didn't say nothing about extra 68 bytes for 17 pointers. This makes 356 bytes. 32 bit integers assumed as pointers.
1. You need 1 pointer to the entire array.
2. Then 4 pointers on the second dimension.
3. Finally 12 pointers on the third dimension.

Answer (score 1):

The answer will vary from platform to platform, and can also depend on the number and nature of previous allocation. Thus the answer you "know" is almost certainly incorrect in some cases.

The answer guaranteed to be correct is that the required amount of memory is "**at least** `4*3*3*sizeof(double)` bytes", which is 288 on most modern platforms.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo What pointers? A 4x3x3 array of doubles should require no pointers to work. In fact, if you use pointers, you're likely doing it wrong because you're adding unnecessary indirections that slow down access and break cache locality.

Comment: I'm just answering the question - dynamically means dynamically, so if you allocate memory for each level separately you need 17 pointers. Even if it's allocated at once but dynamically, you still need at least one pointer to the address of the beginning of the array.

Comment: Except the pointer itself needn't be allocated dynamically, so it's not really included in the question.